# texture <...> not acceptable in VS 2012 & Cuda 5.0:

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-2012, gpu

I have an existing app that compiles and runs fine in CUDA 4.2 and VS 2010. I am now porting to a new system which has CUDA 5.0 & VS 2012.  Unfortunately I *have* to use VS 2012.

I followed the steps to setup CUDA in VS 2012 as in Nvidia forum and [this blog entry](http://blog.norture.com/2012/10/gpu-parallel-programming-in-vs2012-with-nvidia-cuda/), but
my code with lines that reference texture are not compiling, for example:

file:  filter.cu

```
texture < float, cudaTextureType2D, cudaReadModeElementType> texRefEachRes_0;
texture < float, cudaTextureType2D, cudaReadModeElementType> texRefEachRes_1;
```

If I right click on the file I do *not* see its properties as being CUDA, etc. So it sounds like VS still does not know about CUDA?

What else do I need to tweak in VS 2012 to get this code to compile ?

Answer (score 2):

i mis-typed an entry in the Cuda 5.0.targets file;  the process given in the blog entry cited in my question did work whereas the target file included as part of Cuda 5.0 was not correct.  so fixing the bad typing in the xml targets file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution Explorer, right click the project. Select Build Customizations. Select one of the CUDA customization files.

Comment: i have done this -- selected the Cuda 5.0 build rules -- as specified in the blog entry cited -- still not recognized.

Comment: having fiddled around with quite a lot i have found that the problem is that this is a new system and i have only added VS 2012;  the command line that Cuda rules put together insist on MCSV 9 or MCSV 10 whereas what i have on the system is only MCSV 11  so the compilation dies.   Either CUDA and VS 2012 cannot cooperate OR there is some further modification of the rules required to enable C++ compilation with MCSV 11